# up-to-date database of open access policies *and* publication fees?

Tags: publications, open-access, fees

[Sherpa Romeo](https://v2.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/) does a good job aggregating open access policies for a large number of academic journals. This lets me see what OA options (self-archiving of various kinds, full 'diamond' OA with fee, etc.) are available for a given journal. However, it doesn't include information about overall article processing charges (APCs)/OA fees for different routes (e.g., what are the page charges or OA fees for a given journal?)

The [Eigenfactor index of Open Access fees](http://www.eigenfactor.org/projects/openAccess/oa.php) has some information, but seems to be out of date.  The web page says it's "Powered by Eigenfactor.org and [journalprices.com](https://www.journalprices.com/)" but going to `journalprices.com` and clicking "get started" takes you to an [old, slightly broken web page](https://mcafee.cc/Papers/Journal/); the original Excel sheet can be retrieved from the [Wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20190629033402/http://journalprices.com/SummaryData.xls), but was last modified in 2013.

[Academic accelerator](https://academic-accelerator.com) has some information: information seems uneven (is it crowd-sourced?), and the site looks sketchy/ad-heavy/ugly.

Obviously keeping such a database up to date would represent a lot of effort, but I'm curious what the best current set of resources is (an ideal version would have open access to the database *and* would allow easy comparison of journals within a (sub)field ...)

Answer (score 2):

The [DOAJ (Directory of Open Access Journals)](https://doaj.org/) contains curated data about APCs, but only for open access journals.

Here is an example showing a journal without any charges ("Diamond OA") and one with APCs ("Gold OA"):

[image]